# How to set the cursor to busy mode?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, c++

How can I set the cursor to busy-mode/in progress from my qgis plugin (cpp)?

I couldn't find anything in the API documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a normal Qt thing. You can do:

```
QApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::WaitCursor);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, works fine. I didn't knew that i can get the QApplication from Qt, because it's a plugin of QGis.

Comment: Well QGIS is built on Qt so you can use any of the Qt libs